# function for javascript dom style property

Tags: javascript, css, dom, frontend

I want to make a function like this.

```
const displayTextContent = (dom, content) => {
  dom.textContent = content;
};
```

for the dom style property

but when I made a function for this, javascript didn't light up the second parameter in the parentheses ignored the parameter after the style

```
const elementsStyleFn =function (dom, type,s) {
  dom.style.type=s
};
```

and pass parameters like the code below

```
elementsStyleFn(body,backgroundColor,'red')
```

in the consol say (backgroundColor) undefine

I hope my question Is clear enough.

Comment: dom.style[type] = s;

Comment: backgroundColor needs to be a string.

Comment: @Phix 
I tried that but it didn't work
elementsStyleFn(body,'backgroundColor','red')